# How to reset facebook and twitter auth credentials in meteor telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I have set my facebook and twiiter auth credentials, however its throwing a redirect URL error. Is there a way to reset the configuration on telescope and redo the social login set up again.
Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should reset your social login setup (from meteor mongo shell):

```
db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration.remove()
```